# Java: how to verify image file on localhost exists

Tags: java, servlets

This is driving me bonkers. I'm writing a web app in Java and all I want to do is verify the existence of an image that's saved to an /images folder right under the web root.

The 1,000,000 google searches I did seemed to indicate that the File.exists(path) method is the way to go. But for obvious reasons, I don't want to hard code the path.

Physically, the test image file I'm working with exists on my D-drive at, let's say, D:\documents\images\myimage.jpg. GlassFish is my local server and I don't think my image files are replicated to a "GlassFish folder" when my app is deployed, so I think the only physical copy is the one on the D: drive.

The only way I can get:

```
boolean fileExists = new File(somePath).exists();
```

to return TRUE is using the string "D:\documents\images\myimage.jpg". What I was after is a test like exists() that maybe uses a URL that I could couple with some other method or parameter that references the site root and I could build the rest of the URL relative to that.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since documents is the web root, you should be able to use the ServletContext.getRealPath(String) method.

```
ServletContext context = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext();
// Or if you have the servlet instead of request, use this:
// ServletContext = servlet.getServletContext(); // see comment by BalusC
String virtualPath = "/images/myimage.jpg";
String realPath = context.getRealPath(virtualPath);

// realPath will be D:\documents\images\myimage.jpg
```

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)

> Returns a String containing the real path for a given virtual path. For
>   example, the path "/index.html" returns the absolute file path on the server's
>   filesystem would be served by a request for "http://host/contextPath/index.html",
>   where contextPath is the context path of this ServletContext..
>
> The real path returned will be in a form appropriate to the computer and
>   operating system on which the servlet container is running, including the proper
>   path separators. This method returns null if the servlet container cannot translate
>   the virtual path to a real path for any reason (such as when the content is being
>   made available from a .war archive).

Comment: The `ServletContext` is available in servlets by the **inherited** method `getServletContext()`. There's no need to create a session first.

Comment: I thought it would be, but I sure don't see it.  http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

Comment: It's in the [`GenericServlet`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getServletContext%28%29) class which `HttpServlet` extends. Again, it's **inherited**. Just do `String realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(virtualPath)`. See for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506994/writing-a-servlet-that-checks-to-see-if-jsps-exist-and-forwards-to-another-jsp-i/2507158#2507158).

Comment: Very well.  I'm so used to writing code in an MVC framework that normally makes the servletRequest available in action code rather than the servlet itself.  I misread your comment.

Comment: The average framework offers convenience methods to return the raw `ServletContext` without the need to create a session. At least, as far as I know, Spring, Struts and JSF do.

Comment: That's as it should be.  I'm often using a, well, old, proprietary MVC framework that predates all of those, but that will soon change.  Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: This sound like the ticket and I don't see why it wouldn't work. Seems to provide the portability that ensures the path reference won't break when I deploy it to the web. Will do this today. Thanks Fly and BalusC.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can put your images in the war file and use [getResourceAsStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) to get the file?

In that case the path would be relative to the root of the war file