# Should a web framework be a Filter or a Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

Having a web framework handle requests from single point of entry is a solved problem. However, should that single point of entry be a Filter or a Servlet? Why would a web application developer prefer one over the other? Why would a framework developer prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's look how existing frameworks do it:

- [JSF](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/): Servlet
- [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html): Servlet
- [Struts/Struts2](http://struts.apache.org/): Servlet in Struts1, Filter in Struts2
- [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/): Servlet until 1.2, Filter after 1.3
- [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/): Filter *and* Servlet
- [Echo](http://echo.nextapp.com/site/): Servlet
- [Vaadin](http://vaadin.com/home): Servlet

That were the most popular frameworks. There are more, but most of them use a Servlet.

Most if not all servlets are supposed to be mapped on a suffix URL pattern, for example `*.jsf` (JSF), `*.html` (Spring), `*.do` (Struts), etc. This enables the developer to easily ignore resources which are not of interest. So the advantage of the Filter of being able to do that disappears. Only Wicket used to have the need to be mapped on an extra path `/app/*` and the change of Servlet to Filter in Wicket 1.3 was done with the sole argument that you will be able to map it on just `/*`. This however adds extra configuration boilerplate in order to be able to ignore static resources. I personally don't understand why they didn't just use a suffix mapping.

All web frameworks rely on HTTP requests. In a Servlet it's already available straight in the standard methods (often just the `service()` method is been used). In a Filter you would need to cast it back (although this is not necessarily expensive).

Also, Sun/Oracle has made a distinct separation between Filters and Servlets on the following grounds: When you want to **filter** requests/responses on certain conditions, use a Filter. When you want to **control** requests/responses and/or create responses, use a Servlet.

#### See also:

- [Servlet vs Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957165/servlet-vs-filter)
- [Design Patterns web based applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications)
- [How to access static resources when mapping a global front controller servlet on /*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870150/how-to-access-static-resources-when-mapping-a-global-front-controller-servlet-on)
- [Difference between / and /* in servlet mapping url pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern/)

Comment: +1; Although, Struts2 uses a Filter ;-) http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1.1/docs/webxml.html; Also, are you saying that if you want to have a `/*` URL pattern, it is best to use a Filter? For example, if you want to have RESTful paths.

Comment: Ah yes, Struts2 does it a bit differently, sorry for the mistake, I don't use Struts :) As to pretty URL's, you could use an URL rewrite filter like [Tuckey's](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/) one for request based MVC frameworks or framework-specific ones like [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/) for JSF.

Comment: @BalusC - this is pretty much the problem I ran in to http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=9877 so how does a framework like Spring get around to not forwarding back to itself?

Comment: Also looked at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506994/writing-a-servlet-that-checks-to-see-if-jsps-exist-and-forwards-to-another-jsp-i where you say filter is better! I am so confused now. :)

Comment: @Amir: I didn't said that anywhere in the topic and the question also didn't concern a front controller.

Comment: I thought we are talking about a front controller. So if one was to create a framework to handle all requests then would filter be better for reason discussed in the previous post? What do you think? I am just confused on how a controller with /* mapping can forwad to anything without causing infinite recursion.

Comment: @Amir: I think you're confused what the responsibilities of a front controller are. It is not intented to change the request whenever the destination doesn't exist. That was where the question which you linked was all about. The current question concerns a front controller. Read my answer on this question to learn more about the front controller: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot! I was already pretty familiar with Spring but now I get why you have to do /pages/* or /*.do and not /*.

Comment: Check http://www.jtict.com/blog/rails-wicket-grails-play-lift-jsp/. You will find Play!framework (Netty based) + Japid template engine is nearly close to static content hosting (even with concurrent user increased).

Comment: @green: I am not sure how that benchmark is related to the concrete question of whether a web framework should use a servlet or a filter. You seem to be just spamming around.

Answer (score 0):

A web application developer should not really care if it is a filter or a servlet. The developer should simply care about how the framework makes their development easier.

Now, I would even take this further to say that a Web framework does not even have to be based on the J2EE spec (as per the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/)), in which the rules have been entirely re-written to make web applications easier to develop for a Java programmer.

Comment: You really didn't answer my question. I didn't ask about productivity or even what a framework should do. My question also implies the use of Java EE, although your suggestion for not using it is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Filter from personal experience. I came to this conclusion because in the filter I can decide if I need to handle the request. If I don't need to handle it then I can just let the chain do the next filter. In a servlet, if you decide to not continue with the handling then you have to forward which I found didn't work so great.

Comment: Are you saying that having the web framework be a Servlet and writing your own Filter to decide if you don't want the request to be processed by the Servlet wasn't enough?

Comment: I am saying it is either filter or servlet. Not both. With servlets if the path doesn't exist we found it didn't throw a 404 easily. However, after looking at BalusC's answer then may be we overlooked something. :)

Comment: I recall what the problem is now. If a page doesn't exist and your forward to "/missingpage.jsp" it just comes back to the servlet again which causes a recursion and stackoverflow. I wonder how Spring and other frameworks took care of this?

Comment: Even when I try to forward to page that does exist it still goes back to the servlet because I did /*

Answer (score 0):

A Filter is definitely the best choice. A web framework will run as a web application in an application server. The application server will be better for handling some resources, i.e. images and other static files while the web framework should handle calls to dynamic resources. This is easier to achieve if you create a filter that can forward all requests for static resources to the application server (or another filter).

Answer (score -1):

Check [this](http://www.jtict.com/blog/rails-wicket-grails-play-lift-jsp/) benchmark. You will find Play!framework (Netty based) + Japid template engine is nearly close to static content hosting (even with concurrent user increased).

Comment: What does this have to do with my question?

Comment: Sorry my misunderstanding. Have though that your are asking "why should developer prefer one framework over another"