# Uploading file to Glassfish alternate document root folder

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, glassfish

I made an Alternate Document Root for Glassfish in `glassfish-web.xml`:

```
<glassfish-web-app>
    <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/Database/* dir=c:/GetSome" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

JS uploads the file and if it succeeds, then it loads jsp with the uploaded file:

```
function Changed_inputFileLogo()
{
    /*console.log("function Changed_inputFileLogo");*/
    current = event.target;
    var data = new FormData();

    $.each(current.files, function(key, value)
    {
        data.append(key, value);
    });
    data.append("idOrganization", _Organization.id);
    data.append("requestPage", true);

            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            url: 'UploadLogo',
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(response)
            {
                _Organization.logo = 1;
                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                url: 'PhotoExist.jsp',
                data: "path=" + "Database/LogoOrganization/"+_Organization.id+".jpg",
                success: function(response)
                {
                    $("#divLogo").html(response);
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                    LogConsole_ajaxError(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
                });
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                LogConsole_ajaxError(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
}
```

Here is PhotoExist.jsp file:

```
...
<%  String path  = request.getParameter("path");%>
...
        <div class="divPhotoWrapper HavePhoto" onmouseover="ShowPhotoButton()" onmouseout="HidePhotoButton()">
            <div class="divDeletePhoto displayNone">
                <button class="buttonDeletePhoto" onclick="DeletePhoto()"></button>
            </div>
            <a id="aLogo">
                <img id="imgLogo" src="<%=path + "?time=" +System.currentTimeMillis()%>" width="100" height="100">
            </a>
        </div>
...
```

Here is servlet, that copies the uploaded file to Alternate Document Root folder:

```
...
try
{
    filePart = request.getPart("0"); 
    String fullName = Common._FolderDatabase_LogoOrganization + File.separator + idOrganization + ".jpg";
    File FileTemp = new File(fullName);

    out = new FileOutputStream(FileTemp);
    filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();

    int read = 0;
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) 
    {
        out.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
}
catch(IOException exception)
{
    Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to copy file." + " Exception: ", exception);
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED, "Unable to copy file.");
    return;
}
finally 
{
    if (out != null) 
        out.close();
    if (filecontent != null) 
        filecontent.close();
}
...
```

It works fine, but sometimes (one in ten attempts) the browser can't download the image source, and gives this error:`GET http://localhost:8080/GetSome/Database/LogoOrganization/85.jpg?time=1407933088377 404 (Not Found)`. I've tried to check in the servlet if file is available like this:

```
File FileTemp = new File(fullName);
while(!FileTemp.canWrite())
{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

and like this:

```
in = new FileInputStream(FileTemp);
int read = 0;
final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) 
{
}
```

In both cases the file is available, but it doesn't help. I guess that Glassfish does not have time to get access to the file after it is uploaded to a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by checking the availability of the Glassfish resource

```
URL url = getServletContext().getResource(requestUri);
if (url != null) { 
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(UploadLogo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506994/writing-a-servlet-that-checks-to-see-if-jsps-exist-and-forwards-to-another-jsp/2507158#2507158).